# Laptop scratching noise when background visible (not HDD)

Tags: laptop, cpu, noise, extended-desktop

I have a really weird problem but can't find any info or someone with the same problem on the internet.

A few days ago my laptop started making a weird clicking/scratching noise near my cpu. I have an Asus k501ux connected via HDMI to an external 2560x1080 21:9 monitor. Even when I set the resolution to 1920x1080 16:9 the sound is still there.

You can only hear the sound/noise when my desktop is in 'extend' mode and my background (wallpaper) is visible on my laptop screen. When I maximize a program on my laptop screen, the problem goes away. There is no noise when my desktop is in 'PC screen only', 'Duplicate' or 'Second screen only'.

The sound can be compared to an HDD being scratched (scratch, pause 1 sec, scratch, pause 1 sec, scratch, ...). I know it is not my HDD because the HDD inside my laptop is on the other side of my laptop. The sound first reminded me of a cricket :p.
The sound is coming from near my 'esc'-key where my cpu and HDMI-output is located.
There is no difference when my laptop is using its battery or connected with a power cable.
I tried different power options: 'Power saver', 'Balanced' and 'High performance'.
The sound does not go away on either of those settings but the speed of the sound does change. It is fast on 'High performance' and slow on 'Power saver' (the volume stays the same).

I'm not talking about a sound coming from the speakers. It is clearly a hardware sound/noise that wasn't there before (and shouldn't be there).

Can someone help me or give me any tips on what I can try or look for?

(Info: My laptop never fell or anything like that. It was always laying on my desk and wasn't moved at all when the sound appeared.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not a GPU fan kicking in that is slightly misaligned is it? Can't think of much else that would explain the connection between things changing on screen and a physical change within the laptop.

Comment: It could be the integrated intel gpu (but why isn't it making the noise in other desktop modes and only when my background is visible?). I have a gtx950m but that is on the other side of my laptop. I can hear the sound when my fans aren't spinning, so it can't be a fan problem.

Comment: the fans should spin most of the time. the noise might be connected with the video image or system state if it increases load. You may want to check it. Nevertheless, electronics can make funny noise by electronic feedback or whatever. Power supplies are famous for that.

Comment: @Goto-Guru They indeed are spinning most of the time but when the cpu temp is good and I'm not doing anything on my laptop, the fan stops from time to time but the sound is still hearable.

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATE: NOT THE FIX ANYMORE]

You will never believe what it fixed, and I also have no explanation on how and what the connexion could have been.

**I just entered the BIOS -> '*EXIT WITHOUT SAVING*' and never heard the sound/noise again.**

I was looking for an option to turn of C-State or CPU IDLE STATE (C3/C8) because I have seen posts where people say that if you turn this on or off a high pitched noise would disappear. I didn't found the setting, left the BIOS and the noise was gone.
Maybe it was due to a Windows update that perhaps triggered something in the BIOS (if that is even possible), but then I still can't explain why it is fixed by only entering the BIOS.

**Update:**
The noise came back in december (first post was in august). Tried the same thing but it didn't help this time, tried a few more times on different days.

Comment: Upvoted just for finding the problem and updating the question with that info. No clue why though.

Comment: Update: The noise came back in december (first post was in august). Tried the same thing but it didn't help this time, tried a few more times on different days.